# Allow firewall rules for a GCP instance (port:8080) from CLI

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, git-bash, google-cloud-iam

Is there anyway to allow the ports from CLI? 
I have an instance in GCP and I have installed a service which by default runs on `Port:8080`. I know there is an option to change the firewall rules to allow ports from the GCP dashboard but **I'm wondering if there is any way to allow the required ports from the CLI**
In my case I'm using `Git Bash` rather than the native `GCP Cloud Console` 
I have seen the documentation to allow ports from command line [GCP Firewall-rules-from CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/firewall-rules/create) but this is throwing a `ERROR` since I'm using the `Git Bash`. 
Here is the error log:

```
[mygcp@foo~]$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create FooService --allow=tcp:8080 --description="Allow incoming traffic on TCP port 8080" --direction=INGRESS
Creating firewall...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.firewall-rules.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

[mygcp@foo~]$ gcloud compute firewall-rules list
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.firewall-rules.list) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

Is there any option to allow required ports directly from the Git Bash CLI?

Comment: How did you setup gcloud? Does any gcloud command work? Does gcloud work on PowerShell?

Comment: Are you running the command on Compute Engine?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, that one is a E2 VM. But I have connected to that VM from Git Bash.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Compute Engine uses the default service account + [scopes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam) to handle the permissions.

The default scopes limit the API access even if your default compute engine service account has the editor role (by the way, a too wide role, never use it!).

[image]

---

To solve your issue, 2 solutions:

- Use a custom service account on your Compute Engine
  [image]
- Add the required scopes to your current compute engine with the default compute engine service account used on it.
  [image]

In both cases, you must stop the VM to update that security configuration.